# maximum of a function with no constraint

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Consider the function
$$
f(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y^{2}+1}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}
$$
on $\Bbb R^{2}$.

> 1. Find 
>      $\lim_{r \to \infty} \sup_{x^{2}+y^{2} \geq r^{2}} f(x,y)$.

First I find all the critical points and the critical values of $f$ by solving
$f_x=f_y=0$. I got $(-1\pm\sqrt2,0)$ and $f(-1\pm\sqrt2,0)=1/2\pm1/\sqrt2$. On the one hand, for fixed $r>0$ and $0 \le x \le 1$ we can always find $y$ such that $x^2+y^2\ge r^2$. With these $x,y,r$ we have 
$$
f(x,y)=\dfrac{x-x^2}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}+1 \ge 1.
$$
Thus, $\sup_{x^{2}+y^{2} \geq r^{2}} f(x,y) \ge 1$. On the other hand, for any $x,y \in \Bbb R$ such that $x^2+y^2\ge r^2$ we have
$$
f(x,y)=\dfrac{x-x^2}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}+1 \le \dfrac{1/4}{x^{2}+y^{2}+1}+1\le \dfrac{1/4}{r^{2}+1}+1.
$$
Therefore, $\lim_{r \to \infty} \sup_{x^{2}+y^{2} \geq r^{2}} f(x,y)=1.$ 
How does the proof look? I was wondering is there any more general method to deal with this kind of question?

> 2. Prove that $f$ attains its maximum, and find the maximum value.

By checking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Bx%2By%5E2%2B1%7D%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%2B1%7D), I found that this function even has the global minimum. They are indeed the critical values of $f$. But I don't know how to get that.

Any help would be much appreciated.